# jQuery Animate not working on background-color property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I was playing around with the jQuery `.animate()` function, and ended up trying to change the `background-color` of one of the `div`s depending on the number of pixels scrolled by the user. To my surprise, it did not work. I tried using the `.css()` function instead, and it worked well. Please refer the jsFiddle link at the bottom.

Could somebody explain to me why this is happening?

The jsFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/ag_dhruv/cb2sypmu/

Comment: Use jQueryUI for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any ***numeric CSS property***.
>
> **Animation Properties and Values**
>
> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, `width`, `height`, or `left` can be animated ***but `background-color` cannot be***, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used)

<sup>emphasis is mine</sup>

Background Color is not a numeric property and so it cannot be animated using `.animate()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to `animate` the [`background-color`](https://jqueryui.com/animate/) property, you need to either include `jQueryUI` or add this plugin:

```js
$(function() {
  var state = true;
  $("#button").click(function() {
    if (state) {
      $("#effect").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
        color: "#fff",
        width: 500
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $("#effect").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        color: "#000",
        width: 240
      }, 1000);
    }
    state = !state;
  });
});
```

```css
.toggler {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
#button {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#effect {
  width: 240px;
  height: 135px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
#effect h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="toggler">
  <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Animate</h3>
    <p>
      Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Toggle Effect</button>
```

> jQuery UI bundles the jQuery Color plugins which provides color animations as well as many utility functions for working with colors.

Comment: I mean no offence but I believe the question asked **why animate was not working** more than an alternate :)

Answer (score 3):

Just an addition to existing answers: if you don't want to use jQuery UI for this, you can use this jQuery plugin (2.7kB only):

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

You can download `jquery.animate-colors.js` or `jquery.animate-colors.min.js` from the project's website, or include it from CDN:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.color-animation/1/mainfile"></script>
```

After including you can use color animations the following way:

```
$('#demodiv').animate({color: '#E4D8B8'})
$('#demodiv').animate({backgroundColor: '#400101'})
$('#demodiv').animate({borderBottomColor: '#00346B'})
$('#demodiv').animate({borderColor: 'darkolivegreen'})
$('#demodiv').animate({color: 'rgba(42, 47, 76, 0.1)'})
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10923650)

Comment: @joe_young Yes, you are completely right. I edited my answer following your recommendation

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the backgroundColor only with jQueryUI.
If you don't want to use jQueryUI you will need to just change a class and have the animation made in CSS using transitions.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: @PraveenKumar There is no answer for the question because it's not possible to do it with jQuery.

Comment: Ha ha... Sure. But I didn't flag it, just wanted to say it is just a comment.

Comment: @lucian.nicolaescu: There is an answer to this one. OP asked why it is happening this way and so the answer is **No, jQuery animate doesn't support it** (and no, I didn't flag this either) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also animate the background color with jQuery, just not with the animate() method, as you have noticed, the css method will do.

Since this is a very easy thing, do not include another library to the code, spare yourself the http requests and just do it with plain JS.

This function will do just fine:

```
function changeBG(el,clr){
var elem = document.getElementById(el);
elem.style.transition = "background 1.0s linear 0s";
elem.style.background = clr;
}
```

Link to working example

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/wMKowa