# jQuery animate syntax and sequence of animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have an if statement that works (when console.log):

```
if (results['status'] == true) console.log('valid');
```

I am trying to animate a color change on the submit button instead of console.log:

```
if (results['status'] == true) 
$("detail-save-button").animate({backgroundColor: "#aa0000"}, 1000);
```

The first statement works, the second does not. Do I have an error in my syntax? I have code elsewhere to include jQuery.

How would I change it to two animations, one after the next?

Comment: jQuery's animate function doesn't work on colors. Refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838286/jquery-animate-not-working-on-background-color-property/34838309#34838309

Comment: Regarding *How would I change it to two animations, one after the next?* , see the [complete callback in the docs for `.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Turns out the # was the issue in the detail-save-button. I will look at your link DelightedD0D. Thanks!