# JQuery animate complete function doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery

Title says it all really, I've followed every tutorial I could find but my alert() never gets run. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```js
    var right = document.getElementById("right-container");
    right.animate({
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    }, {
        duration: 550,
        complete: function () {
            alert('hello')
        }
    });`
```

Here's a simple fiddle to show the issue I am facing:
https://jsfiddle.net/5shwn8r1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting a dom element, not jquery element, wrap your dom element with `$()`

```js
    var right = document.getElementById("right-container");
    $(right).animate({
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    }, {
        duration: 550,
        complete: function () {
            alert('hello')
        }
    });
```

Or you can select it with jQuery directly : `$('#right-container')`

To animate the `background-color` properties, I also included a jQuery plugin in the `<head />`:

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.color-animation/1/mainfile"></script>
```

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838309/2127277)

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/74c8xu1k/

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code :

```
<div id="right-container" class="container-right">
   <a onclick="switchPage(this)">click me</a>
</div>

<script>
    function switchPage(e) {
        var right = document.getElementById("right-container");
        jQuery(right).animate({
            backgroundColor: '#fff'
        }, 550, function () {
                alert('hello');
        });
    }
</script>
```

**It's working for me and the alert is showing when i clicked on the 'click me' text.**